# Não consigo conectar o localDB com visual studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

Estou tentando usar o *entity framework* no Visual Studio, porém quando tento rodar o programa gera o erro:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
  Class=20
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=0
  Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.
)
  Number=-1983577832
  Server=""
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  State=0
  StackTrace:
       at CursoEntity.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\almeijun\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CursoEntity\CursoEntity\Program.cs:line 29
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

A configuração do arquivo App.config para a conexão está assim:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EntidadesContext" 
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\almeijun\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CursoEntity\CursoEntity\Loja.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

As classes criadas são:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
}

public class EntidadesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            EntidadesContext contexto = new EntidadesContext();

            contexto.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

            Usuario usuario = new Usuario() { Nome = "Junior", Senha = "1234" };
            contexto.Usuarios.Add(usuario);

            contexto.SaveChanges();

            contexto.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta.

Como estou usando LocalDB 20014 a configuração do connection string deve ser essa:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="EntidadesContext" connectionString="Data Source=    (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|path|\LojaEF.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2):

altere seu web config para

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="EntidadesContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SeuBanco;user id=sa;password=SuaSenha;multipleactiveresultsets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

e a sua classe para.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var DBCtx = new EntidadesContext())
            {
                DBCtx.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

                Usuario usuario = new Usuario() { Nome = "Junior", Senha = "1234" };
                DBCtx.Usuarios.Add(usuario);

                DBCtx.SaveChanges();    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu queria que funcionasse com o LocalDB, mas essa solução resolve o meu problema. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso isto funcionou melhor, usando "DataDirectory" no "AttachDbFilename":

```
<connectionStrings>
         <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NomeMeuDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```