# provider: Interfaces de Rede SQL, error: 26 - Erro ao Localizar o Servidor/Instância Especificado

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

[image: erro]
Olá amigos, estou fazendo uma aplicação Web com o EntityFramework usando CodeFirst  e todas as vezes que tento acessar, adicionar ou editar dados tem dado o erro abaixo.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Trabalho com EntityFramework a pouco tempo e sou bem inexperiente, não consigo descobrir onde está o erro.
Segue a connectionString utilizada.

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ProjetoRH" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SistemaRh;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
     </connectionStrings>
```

Muito Obrigado desde já

Comment: Pode colocar sua *connection string* na pergunta?

Comment: tem uma resposta para essa pergunta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98539/n%C3%A3o-consigo-conectar-o-localdb-com-visual-studio/98646#98646)